# how does the "move to trash" or delete option copy files to the trash folder usually?

Tags: linux, filesystems, python, nautilus

Here are what i tried  :

- If a file is deleted , it is copied to Trash/files folder and then it is deleted and its info is stored in the Trash/info in Nautilus.
- So i thought if I make the file non readable , it might not show up in trash since it can't be copied . But when I tried it , it still ended up in trash .
- So i concluded that it directly moves the file to trash directory.

Now here's my question ,

I am trying to mimick this behaviour through programming in python. But what i want to do is to first do some checks and then copy the file to trash before executing the rm command .

I am taking the rm command string from user and then doing some checks and copying the file to trash and then executing the rm command . I don't want to directly move the file to trash . But if i just copy the file , it gives me the permission denied error because of only the read permission . How to resolve this ? Any work around ?

Comment: To copy a file you need to be able to read it, but to move it you need write access to the source and target directories, without any necessity to read the file being moved. You can use `os.remame()`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491232/5164855).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python. I'm using standard Unix commands to illustrate my thoughts. Translate to Python on your own.

Within a single filesystem which is sane enough, [`mv` should be atomic](https://serverfault.com/a/676231). If you choose to move files in two steps, i.e. `cp`+`rm`, then you need to make sure `cp` succeeded before you `rm`. With atomic `mv` there is no risk you end up with the file totally unlinked or "half here, half there".

Moving from one filesystem to another with `mv` is like `cp`+`rm`; `mv` waits for copying task to succeed before it unlinks the original file, still few things can go wrong.

As AFH commented:

> To copy a file you need to be able to read it, but to move it you need write access to the source and target directories, without any necessity to read the file being moved.

True. There is, however, a way to "copy" a file within a single filesystem without reading it: create a hardlink. [Make sure you understand the difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65003/108618).

If you still insist on doing it in two steps, instead of `cp`+`rm` try `ln`+`rm` first. Of course you need to ensure `ln` worked before you `rm`. An attempt to create a cross-device link will fail. In this case you should fall back to `cp`+`rm` (and I think there's no way to do it without reading the file then).

Answer (score 0):

It's 'just' a rename, as pointed out in the comment.

However, there's more than just moving the file involved in putting it in the Trash.  You also need to copy out the metadata to the appropriate location in the appropriate format, otherwise restoring the file won't work correctly.  See the [FD.O/XDG trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) for more info on what all is going on.  Note that pretty much everything uses the optional support for putting a trash directory at the root of removable media, precisely to avoid the issues with trying to trash files you don't have read access to but otherwise can move on that filesystem.